# How do I unsubscribe from "improvement needed" inbox messages on the docs beta site?

Tags: support, global-inbox, documentation-beta

I signed up for docs beta - but have been unimpressed / don't have the time to put into it. I'm getting several messages per week in my inbox... I've searched everywhere but I don't see an obvious way to unsubscribe. Where is it?